# Timestamp does not get converted from Date constructor correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, mongoose

```
console.log("Timestamp: " + data[0].timestamp)
```

**> Timestamp: 1419860543788**

```
var last_date = new Date(data[0].timestamp);
console.log(util.inspect(last_date));
```

**> Invalid Number**

If I create the Date object like this

```
var last_date = new Date(1419860543788);
```

it works all fine, so what's up here? Any idea?
I should mention, that data is a JSON Object (data) returned from the Mongoose find method

```
Blog.find({}).sort({timestamp: -1}).skip(0).limit(10).exec(function (err, data) {
```

Comment: Why not to output result as is?: `console.log(last_date);`

Comment: Also did this. Returns the same. If I call a date method like `getYear()` it returns NaN

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(typeof (data[0].timestamp))`?

Comment: `console.log(typeof(data[0].timestamp));`
 returns string. As it should be, because it's saved as String in Mongo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably `data[0].timestamp` is a `String`, if you convert it to `Number` you can convert it to a `Date` instance:

```js
var data = [{timestamp: '1419860543788'}], log = Helpers.log2Screen;

log(new Date(data[0].timestamp));
log(new Date(+data[0].timestamp)); //<= using + operator to convert to Number
```

```html
<script src="http://kooiinc.github.io/JSHelpers/Helpers-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow thanks. Didn't knew that JS has problems with strings in this case. Solved my problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Michael because `Date` accepts string argument too like `new Date('2014-01-01')` it will not automatically convert string to number.

Comment: Yeah, but I've presumed it :) I'd better RTFM

Answer (score 1):

According to your comments, the value of `data[0].timestamp` is a string.

```
new Date(value);

Parameters

value
    Integer value representing the number of milliseconds 
    since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC (Unix Epoch).
```

Right now, since you're passing a string, which is not an integer/ Number, it'll do this:

```
new Date(dateString);

Parameters

dateString
    String value representing a date. The string should 
    be in a format recognized by the Date.parse() method 
    (IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps and also a version 
    of ISO8601).
```

`Date.parse()` understands dates such as "Wed, 01 Jan 20xx 00:00:00 GMT" and ISO dates, but not timestamps.

If you were to do:

```
new Date(parseInt(data[0].timestamp, 10));
```

You'll get a valid `Date` object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date